# Presetting currentIndex in QML TreeView

Tags: qt, treeview, qml, qt5, qabstractitemmodel

I'm using QML TreeView to list some categorized options for user to select.

Using property TreeView.selection I have assigned SlectionModel to the treeview.
I have a problem with preselecting the item. Using

treeView.selection.setCurrentIndex(idx,3)

I only set the properties of the selection model(the item gets correctly selected/higlighted), but treeView.currentIndex is still invalid. And when using key up/down, it will jump to the first item.

What am I missing?

```
 ItemSelectionModel {
        id: treeViewSelectionModel
        objectName: "treeViewSelectionModel"
        model: myModel
        onCurrentChanged:{console.log("Selectio - current changed from ",previous, " to ", current)}

    }

    TreeView {
        focus: true
        id: treeView
        objectName: "treeView"
        headerVisible: false    //to hide the header

        TableViewColumn {
            title: "Name"
            role: "name"
        }
        model: myModel

        selectionMode: SelectionMode.SingleSelection
        selection: treeViewSelectionModel

        Component.onCompleted: {
            var idx = treeView.model.getPreselected();
            console.log("preselected",idx);
          treeView.selection.setCurrentIndex(idx,ItemSelectionModel.Select);
            treeView.selection = treeView.selection
            //These logged current indexes does not match
            console.log("treeView.currentIndex",treeView.currentIndex);
            console.log("treeView.selection.currentIndex",treeView.selection.currentIndex);

            updateGuiSize();
            treeView.forceActiveFocus();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the treeView.currentIndex and treeView.selection.currentIndex are not the same. If you go to set the value of the treeView.currentIndex, it is accessible only through the hidden variable __listView.

```
        __listView.currentIndex = idx.row
```

**EDIT:**
I found another option

```
         treeView.__currentRow = idx.row
```

Comment: Wouldn't your latter suggestion change the ROW selection, but not the ITEM selection?